# Keep unique ID based on value of a column?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, awk

I have a tab delimited file:

```
GH76.hmm - 358 VENTURIA_I_00885.t1 - 411 7.50E-83 273.9 26.1 1 1 7.80E-85 2.30E-82 272.3 26.1 15 354 24 406 21 410 0.87
GH105.hmm - 332 VENTURIA_I_00885.t1 - 411 7.80E-10 33.7 5.3 1 2 8.80E-07 0.00026 15.5 1.9 63 153 159 250 131 260 0.78
GH105.hmm - 332 VENTURIA_I_00885.t1 - 411 7.80E-10 33.7 5.3 2 2 2.70E-07 7.90E-05 17.2 0.1 12 104 275 378 268 383 0.73
AA3_2.hmm - 570 VENTURIA_I_04612.t1 - 614 2.80E-98 324.9 0 1 1 3.70E-100 3.60E-98 324.5 0 2 566 34 608 33 610 0.87
AA3.hmm - 618 VENTURIA_I_04612.t1 - 614 7.50E-91 300.5 0 1 1 9.70E-93 9.50E-91 300.1 0 81 398 28 609 22 613 0.86
AA3_3.hmm - 591 VENTURIA_I_04612.t1 - 614 2.30E-57 189.7 0 1 2 5.00E-49 4.90E-47 155.6 0 3 463 36 508 34 515 0.81
AA3_3.hmm - 591 VENTURIA_I_04612.t1 - 614 2.30E-57 189.7 0 2 2 3.40E-11 3.30E-09 30.7 0 511 583 531 604 525 611 0.87
```

I want to keep one id from column 4 based on the smallest e-value in column 7. I have tried using below command but no output:

```
$cat ./file2 | sed '/#/d'| sed '/\n/d' | \
  awk -F'[\t]' '$7 > smallest[$4] { smallest[$7]=$4; line[$1] = $0 };END { for (id in smallest) { print line[id] }}'
```

The output should be like:

```
GH76.hmm - 358 VENTURIA_I_00885.t1 - 411 7.50E-83 273.9 26.1 1 1 7.80E-85 2.30E-82 272.3 26.1 15 354 24 406 21 410 0.87
AA3_2.hmm - 570 VENTURIA_I_04612.t1 - 614 2.80E-98 324.9 0 1 1 3.70E-100 3.60E-98 324.5 0 2 566 34 608 33 610 0.87
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
{
  val=sprintf("%.100f",$7)
  a[$4]=a[$4]<val?a[$4]?a[$4]:val:val
  b[$4,val]=$0
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print b[i,a[i]]
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Explanation:

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
{                                            ##Starting main BLOCK of this awk code here.
  val=sprintf("%.100f",$7)                   ##Saving 7th field value in variable val in float form here to make comparison easy.
  a[$4]=a[$4]<val?a[$4]?a[$4]:val:val        ##Creating a variable named a whose index is $4 and checking condition for each cycle if a[$4] is lesser than val then keep its value as it is else change it to current value of val here.
  b[$4,val]=$0                               ##Creating an array named b whose index is $4 and val here with value of $0.
}                                            ##Closing main block for this awk code here.
END{                                         ##Starting END block for this awk code.
  for(i in a){                               ##With for loop traversing through an array a all items here.
    print b[i,a[i]]                          ##Printing array b value whose index is variable i and value of array a with index of variable i.
  }
}
'  Input_file                                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I would like to understand this code, could you please explain.

Comment: @AnjaliChaudhary,I added detailed explanation now, kindly do check and lemme know if any queries here.

Comment: @AnjaliChaudhary, your welcome ma'am, cheers and happy learning on this great site.